# Avoid relative path in Header file includes with Cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, header-files

I have a project structured like below -

```
app
|--src
|  |---module
|  |   |---file1.cpp
|  |   |---file1.hpp
|  |---file2.cpp
|  |---file2.hpp
|  |---main.cpp
|---CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)    
add_executable(testApp)
target_include_directories( testApp INTERFACE src)
        
target_sources(
src/file2.cpp
src/file2.cpp
src/module/file1.hpp
src/module/file1.cpp
src/main.cpp
)
```

file1.cpp

```
#include"../file2.hpp"

//....some code.....
```

**Question**: In file1.cpp, I am including `#include"../file2.hpp"` giving a relative path to file2.hpp. How do I avoid this ??

I am including this path to CMakeLists.txt

```
target_include_directories( testApp INTERFACE src)
```

But when I do `#include "file2.hpp"` I get a `file not found` error. How do I include the `src` folder to my project so that I can use the headers file directly ??

Comment: `file2.hpp` is not in `src/module` but in `src`

Comment: Avoid it by designing correct architecture of your project. If the code in `module/file1.cpp` depends on the code in the header `file2.hpp`, then your `module` should not be "a child" of your directory with `file2*`. How exactly do this, depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gerhardh, yes...I want to avoid the relative path going one folder back and including. Can I modify my CMakeLists.txt to do avoid the relative path

Comment: @pptaszni, so my design is wrong, because module files depends on files from src
But in this case is it possible to modify Cmake to avoid the relative path or its not possible at all ?

Comment: Everything is possible, but it doesn' mean it's less hacky than what you are doing already. `add_executable(testApp ${target_sources})` , `target_include_directories( testApp PRIVATE src )` (you can also add src/module as include dir) and you are good to go. The real question is why would you design it like that. Do you want to reuse your package (then you need to think about public headers)? Do you want to link it against some other module (then maybe PUBLIC incl dirs)?

Comment: You added `src/module` to your include path. What about adding `src` as well?

Comment: @Gerhardh, thanks I corrected my question
The actual issue was changing INTERFACE to PRIVATE

Comment: @pptaszni, thanks changing INTERFACE to PRIVATE in target_include _directory worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[target_include_directories — CMake 3.27.0-rc4 Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)

> The `INTERFACE`, `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` keywords are required to
> specify the
> [scope](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#target-usage-requirements)
> of the following arguments. **`PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` items will
> populate the
> [`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) property of `<target>`**. `PUBLIC` and
> **`INTERFACE` items will populate the [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) property of `<target>`**. The
> following arguments specify include directories.

[INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES — CMake 3.27.0-rc4 Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

> When target dependencies are specified using
> [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#command:target_link_libraries), CMake will read this property from all
> target dependencies to determine the build properties of the consumer.

So basically `INTERAFACE` means that only target which links to given target will have this include directories. Current target build will not be impacted.

Just change this to `PUBLIC`:

```cpp
target_include_directories( testApp PUBLIC src)
```

Comment: sigh. asker edited their question in rev 3 and fixed this themselves. not sure if its better to rollback that edit or what.

Comment: I fixed the path, but INTERFACE is the issue